# TSQL - select rows that contain all items in list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am provided a list of keywords in the form of comma separated string. I need to look at a column in a database table and return all the rows that this column contains all the keywords in any order. As long as the column contains all the keyword, I will return that row.

For example:

```
HeroId    HeroName               
--------  -------------------------
1         Ironman              
2         Superman               
3         Spiderman               
4         Otherman
```

Query string: `'er,man,s'`

Expected result: `Superman`, `Spiderman`

Explanation: only `Superman` and `Spiderman` contain the keywords `er`, `man`, and `s`.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_split()` and some other logic:

```
select t.heroid, t.heroname
from t cross apply
     string_split(@query, ',') s
     on t.heroname like concat('%', s.value, '%')
group by t.heroid, t.heroname
having count(distinct s.value) = (select count(distinct ss.value) from string_split(@query, ',') ss);
```

Comment: Looks like this query returns all the rows with at least one match... Also, isn't this statement always true `having count(distinct s.value) = (select count(distinct ss.value) from string_split(@query, ',') ss);`?